# PHPでクラス図を作成する際、型はどうやって判断？

Tags: php

**下記コードのクラス図は、どう書くのでしょうか？**

```
   class Hoge
    {
        private $p1;
        private $p2 = [];
        public $p3;
        /**
         * @param string $name
         */
        public function __construct($name = null){}
        /**
         * @param string $name 
         * @return Hoge
         */
        public function m1($name){}
    }
```

---

**下記で合っているでしょうか？**

> Hoge
>   -p1
>   -p2 : = []
>   +p3
>   +__construct(name : String = null)
>   +m1(name : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私的になりますが、個人的には下記のようにします。
・"[]"で配列だと分かりますが、"Array"を追加
・関数の返却値型を追加（返却値なし=voidは好みです。"m1"で返却される型は？)
・"__construct"と"m1"の引数をコメントと合うように型を追加

> Hoge
>   -p1
>   -p2 : Array = []
>   +p3
>   +__construct(name : String = null) : void
>   +m1(name : String) : Hoge

Comment: プロパティには型を記載しないのでしょうか？　それとも単に例で挙げたコードからは読み取れないので記載していないだけ？　 また、メソッドの型には「戻り値の型」を書くのでしょうか？　この場合の「型」とは、PHPで定義した型ではなくても良い？　例えば、Hogeクラス(のオブジェクト)を返す場合は、Hogeが「戻り値の型」となるのでしょうか？

Comment: 私のクラス図の書き始めがVBなど関数に型を指定し返却値とする言語から入ったので`返却値の型=関数型`のように記載していました。phpの場合は関数に型指定はなく返却値はある程度は自由なので`+m1(name : String) : Hoge`と記載してもいいかもしれません。(Hogeの返却型が決められているのであれば別)

Comment: 私個人としては`返却値の型=関数型`と記載した方が関数を呼び出した際の戻り値の型が期待できるため共有しやすいと思っています。今見直すと`Hoge`はクラス自身を返すのですね。でしたらクラス図内にも記載があるのでHogeでもいいかと思います。

Comment: 「VBなど関数に型を指定し返却値とする言語」。VBってそうなのですね。「phpの場合は関数に型指定はなく返却値はある程度は自由」。なるほど、分かる場合だけ指定すれば良いのかな、と思いました